# R write dataframe to Excel writes only the column names

Tags: r, excel

I've created a matrix with random numbers:

[image: Matrix of random numbers]

Now I want to export that matrix to a .xlsx file with the following code:

```
x <- matrix(lis, nrow = 11, ncol=6, dimnames = list(c(letters[1:11]), c('1','2','3','4','5','6')))
df <- data.frame(x)
write_xlsx(df, "cijfers.xlsx")'
```

The excel file is created but only contains the column headers like in the following picture:
[image: Exported Excel file]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach

```
library(openxlsx)

lis <- matrix(rnorm(66), nrow = 11, ncol = 6)
x <- matrix(lis, nrow = 11, ncol=6, dimnames = list(c(letters[1:11]), c('1','2','3','4','5','6')))
df <- data.frame(x)
openxlsx::write.xlsx(df, "cijfers.xlsx", colNames = TRUE, rowNames = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)
```